# how to determine if the contour line is circular or not circular using length and width of the contour line?

Tags: matlab

How do i determine if a contour line from contour function, after getting data of the contour, is circular or not.

Is there a way to calculate length and width of contour line so that its ratio if it is closer to 1 it is more circular.

Comment: What do you mean by more circular? Maybe extract the boundary and fit a circle to it then based on the goodness of fitting (e.g. RMSE) determine whether it is "closer" to a circle.

Comment: Yes i have boundary of x y data, how do i determine circularity if i dont have curve fitting toolbox?

Comment: You don't need curve fitting toolbox. There are lots of literature about circle fitting algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Anthony suggested, you may use some circle fitting algorithm such as the [Kasa's algorithm](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-circle-fitting-procedure-and-its-error-analysis-K%C3%A1sa/4cab5d1975ce57a2190d35969086fcaa8c207ea8), which is super easy to implement.

Take `x` and `y` as two column vector input:

```
a=[x y ones(size(x))]\-(x.^2+y.^2);
centre_x = -.5*a(1);
centre_y = -.5*a(2);
radius  =  sqrt((a(1)^2+a(2)^2)/4-a(3));
```

In Matlab you may use `\` to solve systems of linear equations. Check [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) if you are unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Thanks, How do i compute  RMSE with above method?